# Proper size format for DVD conversion

Tags: video, dvd, conversion

I've got a DVD that has it's resolution as 352w by 480h (vlc reports mpg1/2-mpgv ~59.xFPS), which as I recall needs some conversion to look appropriate; I'm planning to upload this video to Youtube so what would be an good conversion to use here?

Should I resize it, and if so what size should I format it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia lists some of the formats you can upload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Uploading). I wouldn't worry about the resolution since I think they convert it on the server side.

Comment: Uploading it as is after combining the seperate VOB files seemed to work out alright; it's not the best quality Youtube converted it to, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The upload process to youtube should keep the aspect ratio, so the image shouldn't be distorted.  It just might have black bars on top and bottom if it isn't the resolution youtube uses, but the only way around that is to crop part of your image. While YouTube recommends a resolution of 320x240, you should try uploading your file as is, because I'm guessing it'll work without any issues.